# Why do I have to re-declare my Classes in an included file?

Tags: php, oop, include

I'm building a website for a client, and he wishes to have a calculator for clients to calculate their monthly premium when they want to lease a car. This calculator appears in three different places in the website, so I decided to build it once, then `include()` the file into the main file. For instance:

```
    case 'calculator':
    case 'bereken-leasebedrag':
        include('calculator.php');
        break;
```

However, I have several classes defined in the main file:

```
use site\database\Vote;
use site\database\Vehicle;
use site\database\VehicleType;

use site\utils\ApiConnect;
use site\utils\Calculator;
```

And some more.

Some of these classes are used by the calculator file, such as Calculator and Vehicle and a few others. These classes are defined in the main file, but are not transferred to the calculator file, whereas variables like $_SESSION, $_POST and even my own defined variables like $car and $calc are available in the included file.

If I don't re-declare my classes at the beginning of calculator.php, it throws a fatal error in the page, saying it can't find, for instance, the class ApiConnect.

Am I doing something wrong here? Logically speaking, included files should inherit pretty much everything, and it seems counter-productive to have to specify every class needed for the included files.

I'm terrible at explaining things, so if I need to elaborate on something, I'd be more than happy to.

Comment: do you have any autoloader registered in PHP?

Comment: @divix Yes, our 'template' includes a file called 'bootstrap.inc.php', and that contains an autoloader. I have no idea how that works though, I'm not _that_ familiar with PHP

Comment: Please show more code. What you do show has nothing to do with file inclusion or autoloading, you're merely showing some namespace aliasing.

Comment: @deceze What would you like to see? I'm kind of at a loss here, everything looks equally strange to me.

Also thanks to whoever downvoted me without saying anything. That sure motivates me to ask something.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "redeclare my classes"? You mean the `use` statements? Well, yes, that's how aliasing works. Again, `use` doesn't load or include a file, all it does is *alias* the class `site\database\Vote` to `Vote` *within the current file*.

Comment: @deceze Aaah I see, thanks! See, I didn't know that because I started learning PHP in the current 'template', so I always took the `use` statement for granted. If I include the classes, would that make them available in included files?

Comment: You only need to `include` the file once somewhere, not in every single file, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), I learned that `use` is used for aliasing, something I didn't derive from my Google searches.

Apparently the autoloader automatically includes all the classes we have, we just manually apply aliasing for every class. Which is kind of weird, but there you go.

Long story short, I had to either apply aliasing in the included file so that I could just say `new Calculator()`, or remove the aliasing and change every `new {CLASS}()` to `new \{PATH}\{TO}\{CLASS}`. I personally went with the first option, but if you have an autoloader and are running into thesame problem, at least you have a choice.